# Eclipse -> Run Button -> Shortcut

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any shortcut key that I can use to run my program? Sick and tired of going to the top of the screen and clicking on the green run button. And yes, I've looked everywhere to find for a shortcut and trust me, I can't find it anywhere.

I'm currently working with Python 3.x and using a Mac.
And no, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+F11 does not work. It only increases my volume.

Comment: Look in the 'Run' **menu** for the shortcuts - things like 'Run last launched'

Answer (score 3):

Alright, so it turns out that to run it without going all the way up would be: Shift + Command + F11.

Is there anyways I can edit this key to a different key? Thanks!

Comment: Key shortcuts can be changed in Preferences > General > Keys

Answer (score 0):

Try F9. On Windows it is working.

Comment: This is an incorrect answer and also brings no value to this question. It is already established that the default key is `Shitf + CTRL + F11` and that you can change key shortcuts in ` Preferences > General > Keys`.

Comment: In my eclipse (out of the box with no shortcut changes) this runs a python script in pydev. It is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, it works for Ctrl + F11 key combination.

Answer (score 0):

Just push Ctrl + Fn (as i guess you have laptop) + F11, ir turn of Fn button in [bios](https://www.google.com/search?q=turn%20of%20fn%20button%20bios&newwindow=1&rlz=1C1CHZN_ruRU975RU975&sxsrf=AOaemvKy8VLPXtYIe8RCNAVmhveO5UdrOA:1640977921734&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=Fmg8-FAyCa1yDM%252CcjiQ30smJoqOSM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kSfhnPZKSb00z1YAYkLKEnSiwErCQ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiOou-Q3471AhUIvosKHSybBOMQ9QF6BAgLEAE&biw=1536&bih=731&dpr=1.25#imgrc=Fmg8-FAyCa1yDM)